# Use MS Graph API to call (MS Teams) to another person from Python Desktop Application

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, desktop-application, microsoft-teams

I'm working on the python desktop application with general idea as follow: a user goes through/follows an instruction and in case of problem he/she asks for help in application. App must call instructor in MS Teams.

[I found Azure Sample in python that helped me login a user and get a token](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-desktop). Then I'm trying to create [a call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) BUT there is a note in documentation: "You will need to register the calling bot..." and the post request has "callbackUri" parameters that I don't see how to get avoid.

As far as I know bots are really just code that runs within Teams and are useless outside of it..

So QUESTION: How to make call from python desktop application (from a real account, not a bot)? Or if you know how to do this with bots, any input will help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Create call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) enables your **bot** to create a new outgoing peer-to-peer or group call, or join an existing meeting. This API is for bot, not for the user.

Also, this API only supports application permissions which not support user to login, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-permissions-consent#types-of-permissions) is the difference between delegated permission and application permission. You could just get token with [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). But the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-desktop/tree/master/1-Call-MsGraph-WithUsernamePassword) is based on username and password([ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)).

[image]

If you want to create call with your bot, the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot#creating-a-new-bot-or-adding-calling-capabilities-to-an-existing-bot) shows how to create a calling bot and add calling capabilities to an existing bot and this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon) is with client credentials flow.

Comment: Right, does it mean that I can't do what I wanted to do? (that is user from the app or app itself calls to the instructor using teams or whatever possible at this point)

Comment: Yeah, user can't call the instructor with `Create call`. You could try to add a bot for that.

Comment: An example call flow that may work for you is get your app to signal the bot (e.g. http rest service) and the bot can "call" the user, when the user answers, the bot can blind transfer the call to the instructor.  Check out GroupCallBot sample as something similar. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/StatelessSamples/GroupCallBot

Comment: That's unfortunate... I'm exploring other ways to implement what I had in mind including bots.  I'll leave the question open for some time, and if there is nothing new - I'll accept this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible to create a call, but what you can do easily is create a "chat" with the other user using Deep Links (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) for more on that) and the user could easily escalate that up to a call using the call button inside there. You'd need to think if that could be sufficient for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I'm exploring any other ways to integrate voice/video chat in the app... I'll look into this direction as well!