# Trigger MS Teams call from a .NET Application

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an idea to create some software by which users can trigger MS Team call (to any number), from any application(Eg. web browser, notepad, etc) within the system.

The challenging part for me is triggering the call from outside teams. After researching, I found:

1. **[Microsoft Teams PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/2.0.0)**: The module does not have any cmdlet for making a call, so it's for no use to this idea.
2. **MS Graph API**: The method includes creating a bot with managing azure account, which will be a somewhat lengthy method and will be dependent on a lot of resources.
   Reference: [Use MS Graph API to call (MS Teams) to another person from Python Desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055047/use-ms-graph-api-to-call-ms-teams-to-another-person-from-python-desktop-applic)

I can make this possible by automation also, but it won't be reliable.
I need to create standalone software.

So, I want to know that can I achieve this by any other method? Like, if I can just trigger the call by hitting commands from the system itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those methods will work for you.  There is no SDK that can be used to do what you want.

There are (as far as I can tell) two undocumented command line switches "tel:" and "callto:".

Both will cause the current running instance of teams to prompt the user to call the thing in the uri.

You use "tel:" for e164 numbers.  e.g. teams e164:+0015555551234

You use "callto:" for teams users. e.g. teams callto:user@company.com