# Start Teams call from c#

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-teams

I'm looking for a way to start a Teams call from within my own custom application.
Our application has a whole bunch of phone numbers for Customers/Suppliers/... and I want to give my users the option to initiate a call just by clicking a button in the application.
Does anybody have a good sample on how to do this?

I know that in the past, this was fairly easy to do with Skype and Lync. They just had an SDK you could call from your own application.
But when I try to look for the same thing in Teams I always end up in documentation around bots. And it's a bit confusing if you're new to that part :-)

So main question is, how can I start a phone call with Teams from my own code? Phone calls to an actual phone number, not a Teams account.

Comment: Would this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031533/trigger-ms-teams-call-from-a-net-application

Comment: That method works. But at the same time it also generates some errors. If it's the only way to go, I can work with it. But I'm looking for cleaner way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: idk not sure never looked into it and don't know how it works excatly but you can join a meeting via clicking on a link and starting teams with the browser. Maybe it works similar with a phonenumber and there is a direct way to trigger teams without opening the browser

Comment: Nvm. Seems that it just starts the exe with the needed paramerters

Comment: Somebody hinted Azure Communication Services. But this needs an extra license cost. Or is this the only way to go nowadays?

Comment: Have a look at this graph API - [Create call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Sample is also available around it. - [Bot calling sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp)

Comment: I looked at this already. I understand that a bot can make a call. But I don't want a bot to make a call. I want my user to click a button and start a phonecall from my application. I don't understand how a bot would be needed in that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such API available to create a call. However you can have deep link to make a call. Follow this doc to understand [Deep linking to an audio or audio-video call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-an-audio-or-audio-video-call)

To make a call to combination of VoIP and PSTN users    `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,4:<phonenumber>`

To make an audio call you can do -
`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>`

To make a video call you can do - `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>&withVideo=true`

User ID field supports the Azure AD UserPrincipalName, typically an email address, or **in case of a PSTN call, it supports a pstn mri 4:.**

It will not directly going to start the call. Instead showing a pop-up as below -
[image]